# How to exit full screen mode for media element in windows 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

Hi guys I have added a video to my application that plays automatically when the page loads and when the video is double tapped it goes to full screen. Here is my code.

c#

```
  private void mediaSimple_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaSimple.IsFullWindow = true;
    }
```

xaml

```
 <MediaElement x:Name="mediaSimple" Source="ms-appx:///Videos/1-Learning-how-to-manage-things-yourself.mpg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  AutoPlay="True" DoubleTapped="mediaSimple_DoubleTapped" />
```

What can I add to my code guys to allow me to exit full screen mode when I touch the screen of my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code like this :

```
mediaSimple.IsFullWindow = !mediaSimple.IsFullWindow;
```

Comment: was perfect love user like you